# onRender event but not after every save

Tags: lightning, lwc-dom

I have a simple component that just pops up a browser alert if a specific field is filled in when the page finishes rendering. I'm not too familiar with the different DOM events and when they fire, but I am using render since load gave me an error. My hope is that I can just have the alert pop up when the page finishes loading, but not after every save. Is there a DOM event that would capture that? Or is there another good way to handle this?

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

```
onRender : function(cmp, event) {
        var myAccount = cmp.get("v.acc");

        if(myAccount.Alert__c != null)
        {
            alert(myAccount.Alert__c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for firing it just once, You can keep a boolean property to  check if page has loaded. Refer the property inside the onRender function to execute your code just once.

```
<aura:attribute name="showAlert" type="Boolean" /> 
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>

onRender : function(cmp, event) {
     var myAccount = cmp.get("v.acc");
     var showalert = cmp.get("v.showAlert");
     if(myAccount.Alert__c != null && !showalert)
     {
        cmp.set("v.showAlert", true);
        alert(myAccount.Alert__c);
     }
}
```